# Using openssl to crypto a file, with the same pubkey.pem the ciphertext is different?

Tags: openssl, rsa

When I use openssl to crypto a file, use the same `pubkey.pem`, but the ciphertext is different?

```
root@09e0b54eb2b5:~/extremelyhardRSA# openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem -in test.txt -out flag.enc1
root@09e0b54eb2b5:~/extremelyhardRSA# openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey pubkey.pem -in test.txt -out flag.enc2
root@09e0b54eb2b5:~/extremelyhardRSA# diff flag.enc1 flag.enc2
```

Binary files `flag.enc1` and `flag.enc2` differ.

[image: command picture]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the cipher text should always look as a random output. So the same message encrypted twice does not produce the same cipher text. If you get the same cipher text, it is leaking information. It happens with masking function and padding functions used by RSA.